# "Run as" option disabled in MyEclipse

Tags: java, groovy, myeclipse

I have imported a groovy project onto my workspace in eclipse. The eclipse installation is all done correctly. I do not find any errors as well. But strangely the "Run as" options are all disabled for this groovy project alone. It is not just the "Run as" option, all the options on right click are disabled. Once in a while I get an error saying "Internal error - Unable to compute launch". Please help me !!

Comment: Sorry, but how is it java related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer! My problem was with package statements. There are too many classes in my project each of them not having a proper package name. Strangely, myeclipse showed this bug in such a scenario!!

Answer (score 1):

Click on the class to execute, click "Run as" click on Run configuration, now go to Java Application, click on new and search the class.